# Android Listview modify all items

Tags: android, listview

What is the correct way to modify all child elements (not only the visible ones) of a listview.
I have an image which is set, by default, to visibilty gone. I wish to make it visible after the user clicks a button (for all items).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the correct way to modify all child elements (not only the visible ones) of a listview.

One thing to understand about a `ListView` is that not all of the list items are generated (inflated/populated) at any given time.

Suppose, for example, your list `Adapter` has 1000 items in it but the `ListView` can only display 10 at once. It would be a very bad waste of resources (e.g., memory) to create all 1000 list items.

Instead, only the 10 visible items are created and each time you scroll one off the top or bottom of the screen, the one which has disappeared is re-cycled by being passed as `convertView` into the `Adapter's` `getView` method.

```
getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

To do what you are asking you should extend whatever `Adapter` type you wish to use and override the `getView` method. In that method check if `convertView` is `null` or not. If it is, inflate your own instance of your list item layout. If it is not null then re-use the UI elements (`TextView`, `ImageView` etc).

To have all `ImageView` elements visible, use a global `Boolean` such as `showImageView` which will be toggled by the button press. Then use that in `getView` to decide whether or not to set the visibility of the `ImageView`.

See [Adapter.getView(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should set the image visibility in your `ListAdapter`'s `getView()` depending on some field value. Upon button clicking you change this field value and then you invoke `ListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged` so the List View updates - `getView` then gets called and image changes because your field value has changed.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `getView()` of your adapter, you grab the ImageView and set its visibility to gone:

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
iv.setVisibility(buttonClicked ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
```

Then when users click on the button, set `buttonClicked = true`, and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` to refresh the ListView.